# Show special characters in concat with db2 sql

Tags: sql, db2

I am running query like this for db2 sql

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('Order_no is =', Order_no), ' for line') FROM orders;
```

And result is coming like this:

```
Order_no is =123456 for line
```

But I want to fetch result as

```
Order_no is ='6640354' for line
```

I need to apply special characters to output, so can you please help me in this.

Answer (score 2):

Use two single quotes together to escape a single quote:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('Order_no is =''', Order_no), ''' for line')
FROM orders;
```

Comment: @KrisshanSirohiya That would seem to meet the criteria for accepting this answer.?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this;

```
select 'Order_no is=''' || trim(Order_no) || ''' for line' from orders;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the use of nested CONCAT scalar is shown so pervasively in db2-tagged discussions, to concatenate more than one value.?  Perhaps caused by how sometimes the documentation separates *expressions* and *scalar functions*, and in the latter docs might only offer a tiny **Note:** *'The CONCAT function is identical to the CONCAT operator. For more information, see "Expressions".'*

I personally find the following use of the CONCAT operator, to be a much more *readable* way to compose the *same* character-string expression:

```
'Order_no is =''' CONCAT Order_no CONCAT ''' for line'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can escape special character using `\` or using another single quote like

```
select CONCAT( CONCAT('Order_no is =\'', Order_no), '\' for line') from orders;
```

Check DB2 documentation on [Escaping special characters](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ts.doc/doc/c0059609.html)